# bash check core exists and is recent

Tags: bash, find

I am looking for a simpler way of doing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

FILE=core
DAYS=1

cd /programdir

if [ -f ${FILE} ]; then
   agetest=$(find . -name "${FILE}" -type f -mtime +${DAYS} -print | wc -c)
   if [[ agetest -eq 0 ]] ; then
      echo "$FILE exists and is not older than ${DAYS} days."
   fi
fi
```

I want to process a core file (using the dbx command) if the script finds it and the core file is recent (within 1 day).  So I would run a dbx command where that echo statement is.  It seems like there should be a way to do this in a more elegant way with 1 if statement, but I can't think of how to do that.  Any ideas?

I know it would be easier to just clean up the old core files with tmpwatch or find/rm, but I'm not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

FILE=core
DAYS=1

if [ `find /programdir -name "${FILE}" -type f -mtime +${DAYS}` ]; then
  echo "$FILE exists and is not older than ${DAYS} days."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks.  I realize where I had -mtime +  that needs to be -mtime -